# Cocoa binding with @sum value of child

Tags: cocoa, cocoa-bindings

I'm trying to have a table column to display the sum of child values using the IB. I'm not sure if this is doable though.

So I have my Core Data bind to a table and a column of "total sales amount" that should be a total of the sales of the parent object.

I'm trying to do it like this:

"departments.@distinctUnionOfSets.sales.@sum.amount" in the "Model Key Path" of the Table Column Binding in IB.

Is there any example or tutorial on how to do this.

Comment: That looks right to me. What problem are you having?

Comment: I keep getting this error:
2009-11-23 23:44:41.864 ClosingTime[3301:a0f] HIToolbox: ignoring exception '[<_NSFaultingMutableSet 0x10031c000> addObserver:forKeyPath:options:context:] is not supported. Key path: @distinctUnionOfSets.sales.@sum.amount' that raised inside Carbon event dispatch

Comment: @SeymourCakes I'm having the same issue (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18333711/cocoa-bindings-get-sum-for-an-attribute-for-all-children) did you find a solution?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using KVC operator e.g., @unionOfSets/@sum in IB's Value Binding Model Key Path](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1800973/using-kvc-operator-e-g-unionofsets-sum-in-ibs-value-binding-model-key-path)