# Cocoa bindings - get @sum for an attribute for all children

Tags: cocoa, cocoa-bindings

I've been trying to get this to work for a while now.

In my Core Data model I have:

Entity `Company` has a one to many relationship with `Employee` (`employees`)

```
Company.employees
Employee.age
```

Using bindings I would like to show the sum of age for all `employees` when clicking on a `Company` in a tableView.

I've tried variations of: `@distinctUnionOfSets.employees.@sum.age`, but can't get it to work.
When I try the above I get the error message: 
`[<_NSFaultingMutableSet 0x10019c430> removeObserver:forKeyPath:] is not supported. Key path: @sum.age`

My `NSArrayController` is bound to `Client` so in IB it looks like this: `Clients.selection.@distinctUnionOfSets.employees.@sum.age`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made this more complicated than it was. Added a new NSArrayController which was bound to Employee.